# How can I align elements and make them have the same height in Compose with ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

There's my code:

```kotlin
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(16.dp)
        .background(
            color = colorScheme.onBackground,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
        )
        .padding(0.dp)
) {
    val (input, submit) = createRefs()
    BasicTextField(
        value = message,
        onValueChange = {
            message = it
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.7f)
            .padding(1.dp, 1.dp, 0.dp, 1.dp)
            .background(
                color = colorScheme.background,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 7.dp)
            )
            .padding(20.dp)
            .constrainAs(input) {

            }
    )
    Button(
        onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp, 7.dp, 7.dp, 0.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.3f)
            .padding(0.dp)
            .constrainAs(submit) {
                start.linkTo(input.end)
                top.linkTo(input.top, margin = 0.dp)
                bottom.linkTo(input.bottom, margin = 0.dp)
            }
            .padding(0.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "SEND", color = colorScheme.onPrimary, fontSize = 16.sp)
    }
}
```

And then I got this:
[image: the button can not fill the black background]

I wanna do that if user inputs something multi lines, the textField's height will be auto change, so if I make the button align top and bottom to the textField, the button will also  changes like the textField. But it's not working.

By Android XML Views, I can easy to use alignTop and alignBottom to do that, but I'm only a beginner with Compose, so may somebody can help me?

Thank you all, salute!

Okey, stack overflow wants to make me input more informations here, minimum 20 characters. I don't know what's this, but thanks to everybody again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Intrinsic measurements for that behavior , by giving the height of your row composable as `IntrinsicSize.Max`.And apply the `fillMaxHeight` modifier to your button.

- `IntrinsicSize.Max` will apply the height of the biggest child composable to the parent composable ( Row in this case).
- As the height of your `BasicTextField` will increase, the height of your row will increase and since the button has `fillMaxHeight()` modifier applied, it will also increase in height.

**EXAMPLE**

[image: visual representation of my masterpiece]

```
                    Row(
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
                        ) {
                            CustomTextField(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.5f),
                                hintText = "Hint",
                                value = text ,
                                onValueChange = {
                                    text = it
                                }
                            )
                            Button(
                                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                               modifier = Modifier
                                    .weight(1f)
                                   .fillMaxHeight()
                            ) {
                                Text(text = "SEND", color = colorScheme.onPrimary, fontSize = 16.sp)
                            }
                        }
```

**CustomTextField**

```
@Composable
fun CustomTextField(
    hintText : String,
    value : String,
    onValueChange : (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    maxLines : Int = 7
) {


    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange =  {onValueChange(it)},
        maxLines = maxLines,
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->  
            Box(modifier  = modifier){
                if(value.isEmpty()){
                    Text(
                        text = hintText,
                        color = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = 0.5f)
                    )
                }
                innerTextField()
            }
        }
    )
}
```

You can change the text font size and maxLines in the `CustomTextField` Composable.  :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, first it's not my wanted, and then look at your screen-record, the button's height changed more than the textField's height.
I found the way to make what I wanted. Add this line in the constrainAs of the button:
```kotlin height = Dimension.fillToConstraints ``` 
It's working for me.